# My internal hard disk has 615 bad sectors and it has no Os installed in it. what should i do to remove these bad sectors and install ubuntu on it?

Tags: hard-drive

I can't install OS on my internal hard disk as it has too many bad sectors. what should i do to remove these bad sectors and install ubuntu on it.

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/128501/smart-disk-failure-05-reallocated-sector-count-creating-a-partition-ubuntu-12 in case you want to take that risk (which I do not recommend).

Comment: Ditch the disk and get a new one .

Answer (score 2):

Bad sector is  error regarding physical of the disk. Instead of isolated the bad sector area, you must change you the hard disk to get rid of the problem. Due to permanent damage that will occurs nearby, the only solution is to replace your hard disk with the new one. Do copy and back up your data before it is broken.